# CosmosDB, help flatten and filter by nested array

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to flatten and filter my json data that is in a CosmosDB.
The data looks like below and I would like to flatten everything in the array Variables and then filter by specific _id and Timestamp inside of the array:

```
{
"_id": 21032,
"FirstConnected": {
    "$date": 1522835868346
},
"LastUpdated": {
    "$date": 1523360279908
},
"Variables": [
    {
        "_id": 99999,
        "Values": [
            {
                "Timestamp": {
                    "$date": 1522835868347
                },
                "Value": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 99998,
        "Values": [
            {
                "Timestamp": {
                    "$date": 1523270312001
                },
                "Value": 8888
            }

       ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to flatten data from the Variables array with properties from the root object you can query your collection like this:

```
SELECT root._id, root.FirstConnected, root.LastUpdated, var.Values
FROM root 
JOIN var IN root.Variables
WHERE var._id = 99998
```

This will result into:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 21032,
    "FirstConnected": {
      "$date": 1522835868346
    },
    "LastUpdated": {
      "$date": 1523360279908
    },
    "Values": [
      {
        "Timestamp": {
          "$date": 1523270312001
        },
        "Value": 8888
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If you want to even flatten the Values array you will need to write something like this:

```
SELECT root._id, root.FirstConnected, root.LastUpdated, 
       var.Values[0].Timestamp, var.Values[0]["Value"]
FROM root 
JOIN var IN root.Variables
WHERE var._id = 99998
```

Note that CosmosDB considers "Value" as a reserved keyword and you need to use an escpape syntax. The result for this query is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 21032,
    "FirstConnected": {
      "$date": 1522835868346
    },
    "LastUpdated": {
      "$date": 1523360279908
    },
    "Timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "Value": 8888
  }
]
```

Check for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#Advanced

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out. My final result is:

SELECT 
    root._id as hpid
    ,root.FirstConnected["$date"] as FirstConnected
    ,root.LastUpdated["$date"] as LastUpdated
    ,var._id as varid
    ,var.Values[0].Timestamp["$date"] as TimeStamp
    ,var.Values[0]["Value"] as Val
FROM root 
JOIN var IN root.Variables
WHERE 
var._id IN (99998,99999) AND 
var.Values[0].Timestamp["$date"] >= 1523270312001
    
A final question is if their is a good way to dynamicly filter on the TimeStamp value which is in UnixTimeStamp. Lets say I want to filter last 5 days from today?

Comment: @baatchen Please mark this answer as the accepted one. Then post another question for the dynamic filter on the TimeStamp.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only looking for filtering by the nested '_id' property then you could use ARRAY_CONTAINS w/ the partial_match argument set to true. The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT VALUE c
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Variables, {_id: 99998}, true)
```

If you also want to flatten the array, then you could use JOIN

```
SELECT VALUE v
FROM v IN c.Variables
WHERE v._id = 99998
```

Comment: Thanks! If I also want 

    {
"_id": 21032,
"FirstConnected": {
    "$date": 1522835868346
},
"LastUpdated": {
    "$date": 1523360279908
    }

for each variables._id how would the query look like then?

Comment: @baatchen What's the final format of result you want? Could you please  sort it in your question?

Comment: You could do this: SELECT VALUE c FROM c JOIN v IN c.Variables WHERE ...